# Flyway hangs on migration execution containing create trigger statement

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

I am using a Spring Boot application with Flyway and MySQL. The versions I am using are:

Flyway: 6.2.3
MySQL: 8.0.33
Spring Boot: 2.2.2

In my migration file, I have the following SQL statements:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS billing;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS billing_audit;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS billing_insert_trigger;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS billing_update_trigger;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS billing_delete_trigger;

CREATE TABLE billing
(
    id               VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    card_number      VARCHAR(255),
    card_holder_name VARCHAR(255),
    expiration_date  VARCHAR(255),
    cvv              VARCHAR(255),
    user_id          BIGINT,
    createdAt        TIMESTAMP,
    modifiedAt       TIMESTAMP,
    payment_method   VARCHAR(30),
    payment_amount   VARCHAR(10),
    months_purchased int,
    full_name        varchar(255),
    billing_address  VARCHAR(255),
    city             VARCHAR(100),
    `state`          VARCHAR(100),
    zip_code         VARCHAR(20),
    country          VARCHAR(100),
    status           VARCHAR(30),
    phoneNumber      VARCHAR(20),
    package          VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE billing_audit
(
    id               VARCHAR(36),
    user_id          BIGINT,
    createdAt        TIMESTAMP,
    payment_amount   VARCHAR(10),
    package          VARCHAR(30),
    action           VARCHAR(10),
    action_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    user             VARCHAR(100)
);


DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER billing_insert_trigger
    AFTER INSERT
    ON billing
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO billing_audit (id, user_id, createdAt, payment_amount, package, action, action_timestamp, user)
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.user_id, NEW.createdAt, NEW.payment_amount, NEW.package, 'INSERT', NOW(), USER());
END //

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER billing_update_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON billing
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO billing_audit (id, user_id, createdAt, payment_amount, package, action, action_timestamp, user)
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.user_id, NEW.createdAt, NEW.payment_amount, NEW.package, 'UPDATE', NOW(), USER());
END //

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER billing_delete_trigger
    AFTER DELETE
    ON billing
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO billing_audit (id, user_id, createdAt, payment_amount, package, action, action_timestamp, user)
    VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.user_id, OLD.createdAt, OLD.payment_amount, OLD.package, 'DELETE', NOW(), USER());
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to run the Spring Boot application, the Flyway execution gets stuck and does not proceed. The logs show the following information:

```
2023-07-01 12:45:19.512 DEBUG 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.scanner.Scanner        : Filtering out resource: db/migration/V79__add_column_open24to7_to_profile.sql (filename: V79__add_column_open24to7_to_profile.sql)
2023-07-01 12:45:19.512 DEBUG 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.scanner.Scanner        : Filtering out resource: db/migration/V7__alter_column_in_notifications.sql (filename: V7__alter_column_in_notifications.sql)
2023-07-01 12:45:19.512 DEBUG 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.scanner.Scanner        : Filtering out resource: db/migration/V80__create_billing_table.sql (filename: V80__create_billing_table.sql)
2023-07-01 12:45:19.512 DEBUG 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.scanner.Scanner        : Filtering out resource: db/migration/V8__alter_column_in_service_info.sql (filename: V8__alter_column_in_service_info.sql)
2023-07-01 12:45:19.512 DEBUG 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.scanner.Scanner        : Filtering out resource: db/migration/V9__alter_column_in_service_info.sql (filename: V9__alter_column_in_service_info.sql)
2023-07-01 12:45:19.842  INFO 19232 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 80 migrations (execution time 00:01.268s)
```

Interestingly, the application works fine when connected to a local MySQL version 5.7.36. What could be the underlying issue causing this discrepancy?

Thread dump(main):

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=5843.75ms elapsed=110.77s tid=0x000001a9bb49f890 nid=11192 runnable  [0x0000007cd8ff9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(java.base@18.0.2.1/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/SocketDispatcher.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryRead(java.base@18.0.2.1/NioSocketImpl.java:258)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(java.base@18.0.2.1/NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/NioSocketImpl.java:347)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/NioSocketImpl.java:800)
    at java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/Socket.java:966)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(java.base@18.0.2.1/SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(java.base@18.0.2.1/SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(java.base@18.0.2.1/SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(java.base@18.0.2.1/FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:533)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:703)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:642)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:941)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:930)
    - locked <0x0000000082ac3a20> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    - locked <0x0000000082ac3a20> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:148)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.tryLock(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:91)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.lock(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:81)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLNamedLockTemplate.execute(MySQLNamedLockTemplate.java:59)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.mysql.MySQLConnection.lock(MySQLConnection.java:161)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:139)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:159)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:137)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:193)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:153)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:521)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$263/0x0000000800e09f10.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    - locked <0x0000000081e16540> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$263/0x0000000800e09f10.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    - locked <0x0000000081e16540> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$263/0x0000000800e09f10.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    - locked <0x0000000081e16540> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$263/0x0000000800e09f10.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    - locked <0x0000000081e16540> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext$$Lambda$602/0x00000008010612d8.onStartup(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    - locked <0x0000000083963ec0> (a org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x0000000083963ec0> (a org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@18.0.2.1/FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(java.base@18.0.2.1/AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    - locked <0x00000000839641e0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    - locked <0x00000000839641e0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x00000000839641e0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@18.0.2.1/FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(java.base@18.0.2.1/AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    - locked <0x0000000083964b90> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    - locked <0x0000000083964b90> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x0000000083964b90> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    - locked <0x0000000083964b90> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x00000000839651f8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    - locked <0x00000000829c8af8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x0000000082c0f3d0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:459)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107)
    - locked <0x0000000083964168> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    - locked <0x0000000081e15d40> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.egumball.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:12)
```

P.S. Everything works fine when I remove the create trigger statements from .sql file

Comment: Take a thread dump and check where exactly it gets stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by separating each trigger statement into individual migration files. It appears that Flyway cannot process and create trigger statements within a single migration. A bug related to this problem has been reported on GitHub: [Flyway Issue 2666](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2666)

In my specific case, I initially attempted to resolve the issue by using a delimiter to separate the trigger statements in a single migration file. However, this approach did not work. Eventually, I found that separating the trigger statements into different migration files, as mentioned above, successfully resolved the issue.